# Azure Portal BizSpark Subscription - Is there any Max limit and cost for adding Users?

Tags: azure, user-management, users, entra-id

I am having Azure BizSpark Subscription in Azure Portal, and I want to add Guest Users and grant them roles/resources separately. I searched documentations but not able to find whether adding Guest users or simple users in Azure Portal has any maximum limit? And whether adding/management of user and roles has any pricing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the limits for the subscripton, please read this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits).

For the user, A maximum of 100 users can be owners of a single application. For other limits about the Azure AD service, please refer to [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-service-limits-restrictions).

And there is no paying only for adding/management of user and roles. For the details pricing about Azure AD, please refer to [Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/).

Comment: Hope it is useful for you.

Comment: Yes it surely is